# AngularJS ng-show crashing the whole application

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-show, ng-hide

I'm using AngularJS and what I've encountered is ng-show crashing my whole web application. On the other hand using ng-hide works perfectly fine. Here's a code snippet:

```
Image.get({project_id: $scope.project.id}, function(images_data) {
    $scope.project.images = images_data.images;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            openEffect: 'none',
            closeEffect: 'none'
        });
    });
    display_images();
});
```

and HTML:

```
<div ng-show="project.images.length > 0">
```

And here comes the crash. When I change `ng-show` to `ng-show="project.images.length == 0` everything is back to normal. This is only aesthetic problem and I don't mind using ng-hide, but I'd like to find out what's happening there. Thanks is advance!

@edit The output from console is

```
Error: Script terminated by timeout at:
display_images/<@127.0.0.1:8000/static/app/js/app.js:50:1
jf/this.$get</n.prototype.$digest@127.0.0.1:8000/static/angularjs-1.4.2/angular.min.js:132:257
jf/this.$get</n.prototype.$apply@127.0.0.1:8000/static/angularjs-1.4.2/angular.min.js:135:267
l@127.0.0.1:8000/static/angularjs-1.4.2/angular.min.js:87:232
F@127.0.0.1:8000/static/angularjs-1.4.2/angular.min.js:91:277
Tf/</K.onload@127.0.0.1:8000/static/angularjs-1.4.2/angular.min.js:92:315
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.2/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
```

and I posted everything relevant from the code here: http://pastebin.com/iqx6YsX3

Comment: what you mean _crashing my whole web application_? can you provide error message?

Comment: What is `images_data.images`? Is it a promise?

Comment: the error is briefly "script not responding at /static/app/js/app.js:50", which is the snippet I pasted above. i'm using polish translated browser, so copying the whole error is pointless :D

Comment: `images_data.images` it is a response I get from my GET request

Comment: i think whole error needed anyway :-) if you can't get engilsh error you can simple translate from polish

Comment: So it goes like: "Script on this webpage might be busy or stopped responding. You can terminate the script now, open it in debugger or let it proceed. Script: /static/app/js/app.js:50"

Comment: can you also provide [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) that can reproduce your problem?

Comment: can you try remove `$(document).ready(...)` and check? and provide `display_images`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84712/discussion-between-grundy-and-nhor).

Comment: Just use ng-show="project.images.length". If it is zero it is evaluated as falsy, otherwise it's true. Pretty sure the >/< opererators are not supported in angular expressions.

Comment: nevertheless it's not the problem, both `ng-show="project.images.length"` and `ng-show="project.images.length > 0"` cause the error

Answer (score 0):

Suspect the `>` might be causing problems here.

You could add the decision to your controller instead:

```
$scope.hasImages = function() {
    return $scope.project.images.length > 0;
}
```

And then:

```
<div ng-show="hasImages()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are dealing with `Uncaught ReferenceError: images(or project) in not defined`, 
to make it safe you can use following expression:

```
<div ng-show="project && project.images && project.images.length > 0">
```

but if you want to check for length than this would be in fact sufficient

```
<div ng-show="project && project.images && project.images.length">
```

Comment: Can you provide output from console (eg: in Chrome web developer console) ?

Answer (score 0):

The ngShow directive shows or hides the given HTML element based on the expression that provide true of false value.

No Control Flow Statements: You cannot use the following in an Angular expression: conditionals, loops, or exceptions.

you cannot write a control flow statement in an expression. The reason behind this is core to the Angular philosophy that application **logic should be in controllers**, not the views. If you need a real conditional, loop, or to throw from a view expression, delegate to a JavaScript method instead.

[You can see more info from here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

If you want to use expression in UI You may got Uncaught ReferenceError for project or image so should check first project then image then length

```
<div data-ng-show="project && project.images && project.images.length">
```